# Is there a way to add a constant field to Serde's serialized output?

Tags: rust, serde

I want to add a field to the serialized output of a struct, but I don't want that field to be a member of the struct or to use custom serialization.

Is there a way to do something like this, with the `serde(add_int_field` being my hypothetical attribute:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(add_int_field = "version", value = 1)]
struct MyStruct {
    a: String,
}
```

would output

```js
{
  "a": "something",
  "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you need it? Unless you prefer `Self { ... }` to `Self::new(...)` when creating an object

Comment: so I don't need to add a field in the struct for that json field.

Comment: `#[serde(skip_deserializing)]` and ``#[serde(skip_serializing)]``?